# как суммировать значение базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql

как суммировать значение базы данных?

У нас есть

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT norma FROM datele WHERE model = '$models' AND pachet START LIKE 5 AND pachet FINISH LIKE 25 ORDER BY operatie");  
$total = sum($result)
```

Идея в том что он должен выбрать колонку norma где model = $model и он должен подсчитать все значение которые начинаются от pachet 5 и до 25

как можно это реализовать?

Comment: числовые поля сравниваются числовыми операторами сравнения, а не в коем случае не like. например `pachet between 5 and 25`

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
Есть к примеру три записи в БД, в каждой записи в ячейке COL разные числа. К примеру: 
1) - COL = 2
2) - COL = 3
3) - COL = 4





    $rep1=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`col`) AS `summa` FROM temp_pack WHERE login='".$_SESSION['Logs']."' AND type='$type'");





 по аналогии думаю можно и у Вас реализовать
```

Comment: да но как реализовать что-бы он подсчитал sum только 2) и 3) 

выборочна

Comment: Как ваш ответ решает задачу автора вопроса? Какая информация содержится в колонке type?